# Why is it so that when geolocation ran on Firefox gives more accurate results as compared to Chorme

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, geolocation

Is there a specific reason as to why geolocation(javascript class for coordinates) is giving accurate results on Mozzila Firefox as compared to Google Chrome?

Here is the javascript code:

'''

```
    var x;

    function getTargetWeather(targetElm){
        x = document.getElementById(targetElm);
        getLocation();
    }
    

    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
            } else {
            x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
      }
  }

    function showPosition(position) {
                    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
                    "   Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
    }


    function copyCoords(){
        var copyText = document.getElementById("demo");
        copyText.select();
        copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
        document.execCommand("copy");
    }


$(document).ready(function(){
    getTargetWeather("demo");
});
```

'''

Comment: *"is giving accurate results on Mozzila Firefox as compared to Google Chrome"* Define what you mean by "accurate" (by which I assume you mean *more* accurate). What are you seeing that makes you think the results on Firefox are more accurate than the results on Chrome? (And do you really mean [*accurate*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/accurate), or [*precise*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/precise)? )

Comment: They both are giving a certain result every time the code is ran, (eg, when the code is ran chrome gives the latitude to be 29.05, whereas firefox gives 28.46 which is closer to the result and hence more "accurate")

Comment: in windows 10, firefox can access location info that the operating system has, chrome does not - I've put my precise location into windows 10 - so, firefox gets it right ... chrome is using some other method to determine my location